# iOS: Change contentsize of a UIScrollview using auto layout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios6, autolayout

I'm implementing a form inside a `UIScrollView`. I'm trying to add some space at the bottom of the content of a scroll view when the keyboard is opened so the user can see all the fields. I put the form view inside the `UISCrollView` adding all the needed constraints with the following code:

```
 [_infoView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_infoView(1730)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[_scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_infoView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[_scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_infoView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[_scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_infoView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:_scrollView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                       multiplier:1
                                                         constant:0]];
```

As you can see, I specify in the first line the height of the form and the `scrollview` adapts its content size automatically. Now I want to increase the height of the form, so I've tried to reset the constraint for the height with a greater one but it won't work. Then I've tried to use the `[_scrollView setContentSize:]` method but this also won't work. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having an awful time figuring this out.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not sure where you add the above code, but the below should solve your problem

In Your init Function, add the below:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(noticeShowKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(noticeHideKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Add the below to your .h

```
CGSize keyboardSize;
int keyboardHidden;      // 0 @ initialization, 1 if shown, 2 if hidden
```

Add the below to your .m

```
-(void) noticeShowKeyboard:(NSNotification *)inNotification {
    keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    keyboardHidden = 1;
    [self layoutSubviews];        // Not sure if it is called automatically, so I called it


}
-(void) noticeHideKeyboard:(NSNotification *)inNotification {
    keyboardHidden = 2;
    [self layoutSubviews];       // Not sure if it is called automatically, so I called it

}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if(keyboardHidden == 1) {
        scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(scrollview.frame.origin.x, scrollview.frame.origin.y, scrollview.frame.size.width, scrollview.frame.size.height + keyboardSize.height);
    }
    else if(keyboardHidden == 2) {
        scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(scrollview.frame.origin.x, scrollview.frame.origin.y, scrollview.frame.size.width, scrollview.frame.size.height - keyboardSize.height);
    }
}
```

I overrided `layoutsubviews`, now I think it should work.

Comment: The problem is that if your nib is using auto layout rect sizes are managed by constraints and setting them diretcly wont work

Comment: Check the edited answer, overriding `layoutsubviews` should solve your problem ...

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the problem, I would recommend adjusting the `contentInset` property on the `UIScrollView` rather than call `layoutSubviews`. Note that the docs say:

> Use this property to add to the scrolling area around your content. The unit of size is points. The default value is `UIEdgeInsetsZero`.

You still have to listen for the keyboard hide/show notifications so as to know when to adjust the height of your scrollview:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Then in `keyboardWillShow` you can do this:

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0);
scrollView.contentInset = insets;
```

`100` is the height by which you want to adjust your `scrollView`. I do this with a `UITableView` in which I have form elements as `UITableViewCell`s and it works well.